# Pandas: Parsing with two conditions issue

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe called `transcripts` and a numpy array called `genes`. `genes` is simply the unique values of the `geneID` column of `transcripts`. For each value of `genes` I would like to find the longest transcript (column `transcriptLength` in `transcripts`), and remove all others from the `transcripts` dataframe. I thought I would use the code below and then loop through `genes`.

```
#subset transcripts, leaving only rows with id of genes[20000]
x=transcripts.loc[(transcripts['geneID'] == genes[20000])].copy()
#Find longest transcript    
y = x.transcriptLength.max()
#subset transcripts df to remove all transcripts that are shorter for that gene
z=transcripts.loc[(transcripts['geneID'] != genes[20000]) & (transcripts['transcriptLength'] != y)].copy()
```

However, for some reason this code removes all transcripts with that `geneID`. I have subsetted before like this (and looked at other similiar stack questions) and my code appears to be correct so I cannot fathom what the issue is. Is there something missing here?

FYI `geneID` column is strings, whilst `transcriptLength` column is ints.
Here is the first rows of `transcripts`:

```
geneID  transcriptID    transcriptLength
0   ENSPTRG00000042638  ENSPTRT00000076395  71
1   ENSPTRG00000042646  ENSPTRT00000076407  949
2   ENSPTRG00000042654  ENSPTRT00000076381  69
3   ENSPTRG00000042645  ENSPTRT00000076409  1558
4   ENSPTRG00000042644  ENSPTRT00000076406  75
```

EDIT: Here is a toy example, where we are trying to find the longest transcript for gene g2 and remove any that are shorter:

```
#Create dataframe (akin to transcripts above)
d = {'transcriptID' : pd.Series(['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 
     'geneID' : pd.Series(['g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g2'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
    'transcriptLength' : pd.Series([212, 715, 213, 984], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#Subset df to include only values where geneID = g2
x=df.loc[(df['geneID'] == 'g2')].copy()
#Find max transcriptLength
y = x.transcriptLength.max()
#Subset main df to remove all g2 values except the maximum one
z=df.loc[(df['geneID'] != 'g2') & (df['transcriptLength'] != y)].copy()
```

This outputs:

```
    geneID  transcriptID    transcriptLength
a   g1  t1  212
c   g3  t3  213
```

It has removed all rows with `geneID` of `g2`. It is only supposed to remove row `b` (which had the lowest value of all the `g2` geneIDs). Row `d` has also been removed, which is incorrect.

Comment: Is it because you have `z = ... != genes[20000]) & ...` where you meant `z = ... == genes[20000]) & ...`?

Comment: But I am trying to subset so that only transcripts that are NOT genes[20000] AND are also NOT max length for that gene? So I would need to have != genes[20000]), otherwise I am left with just the rows that I am supposed to remove, rather than the ones I want to keep.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. You said that _"for some reason this code removes all transcripts with that geneID"_? I think you need to provide a minimal working example: a small sample input and what your desired output should be.

Comment: I have added a toy example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `z=df.loc[(df['geneID'] != 'g2') | (df['transcriptLength'] == y)].copy()`, i.e. you want 'or' instead of 'and'. So anything outside of g2, you keep, and if it's in g2, you want it not to have transcriptLength y. As currently written, you reject anything unless it is both not in g2 and does not have that transcriptLength.

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. I changed the second statement to ==: z=df.loc[(df['geneID'] != 'g2') | (df['transcriptLength'] == y)].copy() Otherwise it is the one that is to be rejected that is kept.

Comment: @spiral01 oops quite right, I've edited the answer to reflect that change

Answer (score 2):

Your boolean logic is incorrect. You can change it to:

```
z=df.loc[~((df['geneID'] == 'g2') & (df['transcriptLength'] != y))].copy()
```

Where the `~` is the `not` operator. This logic says discard all the rows where `geneID == g2` and `transcriptLength != y`.

You want to keep the rows under both of the following conditions:

```
(df['geneID'] == 'g2') & (df['transcriptLength'] == y)
df['geneID'] != 'g2'
```

The code as you had written was eliminating all rows where `df['geneID'] == 'g2'`.

If you're still unclear about it, try writing out the truth tables.

Comment: Sorry what does the ~ do? Also, this statement changes the order of the initial dataframe. Is there a reason it does this?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain the `~`. I am not sure about the ordering. Also, I don't think you need the `.copy()`